# jQuery image slider - restart from beginning when images run out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this very simple (and probably not built the recommended way) image slider at my wordpress page that I built myself. My problem is that when the images run out, it will just slide whitespace, and so on. I want it to start sliding from the beginning, or just stop sliding at the last image. Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-wrap">
   <div id="gallery">
      <img class="galleryimage" src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/ccc.PNG" alt="" />
      <img class="galleryimage2"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/coverline.PNG" alt="" />
      <img class="galleryimage3"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/ccc.PNG" alt="" />
      <img class="galleryimage4"  src="http://materiaalit.kotisivut.name/sivustokuvat/coverline.PNG" alt="" />
   </div>
    <div id="gallery-controls">
      <a id="gallery-prev" href="#"><img alt="" /> </a>
      <a id="gallery-next" href="#"><img alt="" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery-wrap{margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative; height:300px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:6px; z-index:3;}
#gallery{position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; width:100%;}
.galleryimage{position:absolute; width:100%; height:300px; top:0px;}
.galleryimage2{position:absolute; width:100%; height:300px; left:100%;top:0px;}
.galleryimage3{position:absolute; width:100%; height:300px; left:200%;top:0px;}
.galleryimage4{position:absolute; width:100%; height:300px; left:300%;top:0px;}

#gallery-controls{width: 100%; z-index:4;}
#gallery-prev{position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:50%; height:300px; }
#gallery-next{position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;  width:50%; height:300px;}
```

And the js/jquery

```
var position = 1; // you always start at the first image?
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#gallery-prev").click(function(){

    var nr_of_img = $('img', $('#gallery')).length;

    if (position == 1)
    { 
      // move all the way to the last image
      position = nr_of_img;
    }
    else
    {$("#gallery").animate({"left": "+=100%"}, "slow");
      // move to the previous image
      position--;
    }
  });

  $("#gallery-next").click(function(){

    var nr_of_img = $('img', $('#gallery')).length;

    if (position == nr_of_img)
    { 
      // move all the way to the first image
      position = 1;
    }
    else
    {$("#gallery").animate({"left": "-=100%"}, "slow");
      // move to the previous image
      position++;
    }
  });
});
```

So as you can probably see, I'm thinking what to put in the variables. How does the script know when the images run out? And as you can see, the images are absolutely positioned, that was the easiest way to get them all to the same horizontal line. 
If anyone wants to see this in action:
http://wordpress.kotisivut.name/

Comment: Not sure but tbh there are thousands of pre-built versions of this out there so why reinvent the wheel? Good to know how to do it from scratch I guess but from a project time point of view not really worthwhile.

Comment: To learn some js for example. I'm really bad at it, and I want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you count the amount of images in your slider...

```
var nr_of_img = $('img', $('#gallery')).length;
```

Then you can keep count of the number of moves you make from left to right etc and see if you ran out of images.

**[Edit]**

first of all your if-statements are at the wrong place. You want to do the if-statements in the event functions.

This would mean you would do something like this

```
var position = 1; // you always start at the first image?
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
    var nr_of_img = $('img', $('#gallery')).length;

    if (position == 1)
    {
      // move all the way to the last image
      position = nr_of_img;
    }
    else
    {
      // move to the previous image
      position--;
    }
  });

  $("#gallery-next").click(function(){
    var nr_of_img = $('img', $('#gallery')).length;

    if (position == nr_of_img)
    {
      // move all the way to the first image
      position = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      // move to the previous image
      position++;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: So I did this, and so on, but now I'm wondering the if statements. What to write to the other side of the condition?
`if(hasImagesLeft != ??){`

Comment: I added an example of how I would do it. Your approach would not work because the if statement is around the binding of the event. Once the binding has been done your if statements will never be executed again.

Comment: Need more info than that to be able to help you.

Comment: Well, it simply doesn't slide any images.

Comment: Because you have to add your own code for sliding them left and right... I didn't ad that. Sorry I should have made that more clear. Your code for moving the divs around worked i guess... So you have to add that stuff to my code. I didn't now completely program it for you. I just showed you how it should look like. The places where i added comment you should add your own code for moving the images around.

Comment: Okay, I added my rows to that. Now it slides, but when I have reached the last image, and I click the next or previous button twice, it will slide normally. So what I'm possibly doing wrong here? I edited the code in my question.

Comment: Ok, a friend of mine asked why position = 1; and told me to try position == 1; and it wont scroll over the images anymore.

Comment: you start at your first image so basically when you load the page the position is 1... you and and substract values of 1 to keep track of where you are in your image slider

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [Count number of files in a folder through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266004/count-number-of-files-in-a-folder-through-javascript)

2. With PHP you can have the filecount as

   ```
   $directory = "../images/team/harry/";
   if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false)
   {
    $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
    echo $filecount;
   }
   else
   {
    echo 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't want to use php for this.