# Simple local folder file count to create a for loop based on elements contained

Tags: javascript, arrays

As simple as it is and as newbee I am, I fail to find a simple answer to that.
In my html index I need to create a loop based on the number of files with extension .obj of a folder in the same directory ..assets . grab the number of files with this extension and use it for a for loop. What would be the code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of files in a folder through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266004/count-number-of-files-in-a-folder-through-javascript)

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far and any error messages you may be getting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are talking about NodeJS, JavaScript runs (in a sandbox) on the CLIENT so it is not possible to do what you want. You would have to use a server side technology such as Ruby, Python, PHP etc.